# Radio button issue returning null object reference

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm currently working on a prototype for a section of an application I'm working on. In short, its an application that draws onto a canvas, it will be used as a floor plan editor when finished.

I've built a section for adding new items to the canvas, using multiple alert dialog windows, each one with a new input, and the last for confirmation.

Currently, the first alert dialog allows the user to select either a table or bar stool to add to the canvas, through the use of radio buttons. I've been trying to get the application to send the string value of the radio button through to the next function.

When I run this code with the debugger, it returns a null object reference when attempting to invoke .getCheckedRadioButtonId(). I've looked around at some other solutions but so far no luck. I've put my code and the relating files below.

EditFloorPlan.kt

```
package com.example.prototype_floorplan

// imports
import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.RadioGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

class EditFloorPlan : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_floorplan)

        // defines initial actions within this view
        val addNew: FloatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.addNew)
        val toPrevious: FloatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.toPrevious)
        val imageView: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.editableLayout)

        // sets on click listeners on both floating action buttons
        addNew.setOnClickListener {
            // calls function addTable on button press
            addTable()
        }

        toPrevious.setOnClickListener {
            // returns the user to the previous activity
            onBackPressed()
        }
    }

    private fun finalDialog(inputText: String, stringToSend: String) {
        // defines layout inflater as inflater
        val inflater = layoutInflater
        // builds second alert dialog and inflates the layout with final_popup.xml
        val finalWindowLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.final_popup, null)
        // defines both text views within this alert dialog and assigns text to those views
        val textViewOne = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.num_chairs)
        val textViewTwo = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.item_selection)
        textViewOne.text = inputText
        textViewTwo.text = stringToSend
        // defines alert dialog and sets view according to final_popup.xml
        val finalPopup = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        finalPopup.setView(finalWindowLayout)

        // defines title and message for the alert dialog
        finalPopup.setTitle("Confirm Addition")
        finalPopup.setMessage("Confirm your selection?")

        // defines positive and negative reactions within the final alert dialog
        finalPopup.setPositiveButton("Confirm & Add") { dialog, id -> run {
            // dismisses the alert dialog on positive reaction and calls function draw()
            dialog.dismiss()
            draw(inputText, stringToSend)
        } }

        finalPopup.setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, id -> run {
            // dismisses the alert dialog on negative reaction
            dialog.cancel()
        } }

        // creates and displays the final alert dialog window
        finalPopup.create()
        finalPopup.show()
    }

    private fun nextDialog(stringToSend: String) {
        // defines layout inflater as inflater
        val inflater = layoutInflater
        // builds second alert dialog and inflates the layout with next_popup.xml
        val nextWindowLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.next_popup, null)
        // defines edit text as userInput and stores user input as inputText
        val userInput = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.userInput)
        val inputText = userInput.text.toString()
        // defines alert dialog and sets view according to next_popup.xml
        val nextPopup = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        nextPopup.setView(nextWindowLayout)

        // defines title and message for the alert dialog
        nextPopup.setTitle("Num. Of Chairs")
        nextPopup.setMessage("How many chairs does this object have?")

        // defines positive and negative reactions within the second alert dialog
        nextPopup.setPositiveButton("Next") { dialog, id -> run {
            // dismisses the alert dialog and calls function finalDialog() with the inputText parameter
            dialog.dismiss()
            finalDialog(inputText, stringToSend)
        } }

        nextPopup.setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, id -> run {
            // dismisses the second alert dialog on negative reaction
            dialog.cancel()
        } }

        // creates and displays the second alert dialog window
        nextPopup.create()
        nextPopup.show()
    }

    private fun addTable() {
        // defines layout inflater as inflater
        val inflater = layoutInflater
        // builds first alert dialog and inflates the layout with popup_window.xml
        val popupWindowLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_window, null)
        // defines radio group in popup_window.xml
        val radioGroup = findViewById<RadioGroup>(R.id.addSelection)
        // defines alert dialog and sets view according to popup_window.xml
        val popupWindow = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        popupWindow.setView(popupWindowLayout)

        // defines title and message for the alert dialog
        popupWindow.setTitle("Add New")
        popupWindow.setMessage("What object would you like to add?")

        // defines positive and negative reactions within the alert dialog
        popupWindow.setPositiveButton("Next") { dialog, id -> run {
            // defines radio group within popup_window.xml
            val radioID: Int = radioGroup.checkedRadioButtonId
            // if radio id is equal to either radio button, dismiss the dialog and call function nextDialog, with parameter stringToSend
            if ( radioID == R.id.radio_selection_1) {
                val stringToSend = "Table"
                dialog.dismiss()
                nextDialog(stringToSend)
            }

            else if (radioID == R.id.radio_selection_2) {
                val stringToSend = "Bar Stool"
                dialog.dismiss()
                nextDialog(stringToSend)
            }
        } }

        popupWindow.setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, id -> run {
            // dismisses the first alert dialog on negative reaction
           dialog.cancel()
        } }

        // creates and displays the first alert dialog window
        popupWindow.create()
        popupWindow.show()
    }

    private fun draw(inputText: String, stringToSend: String ) {

    }
}
```

popup_window.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/popup_window"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RadioGroup
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/addSelection"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RadioButton
        android:text="Table"
        android:id="@+id/radio_selection_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RadioButton
        android:text="Bar Stool"
        android:id="@+id/radio_selection_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

In theory, each alert dialog here has a different input, and each input in passed along through the functions until the last alert dialog, where a confirmation is shown with the relating data from the first two alert dialogs. Just currently, it doesn't move passed the first alert dialog because of the null object reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using findViewById on the correct layout. You are inflating the popupWindowLayout, but trying to find the RadioGroup on your activities layout.

Replace
`findViewById<RadioGroup>(R.id.addSelection)`

By
`popupWindowLayout.findViewById<RadioGroup>(R.id.addSelection)`